# What happens if Millis() method variable goes out of it's capacity?

Tags: arduino-uno, millis

I am now working on a project which is expected to last at least 5 years from the time it is completed. In that project, i can not use delay() for some purposes so I am using millis() method

```
unsigned long Then = 0;
unsigned long Threshold = 1000;

void setup(){
    // Codes
}


void loop(){
    unsigned long Now = millis();
    if(Now-Then>=Threshold){
        // Execute a function or functions
        Then = Now;
    }
}
```

Now in this code wee can see the variable 'Then' and 'Now' are getting updated whenever threshold is met.

So now, suppose after a certain period of time (without any switch off), if any one of the two ever-updating variables which are 'Now' or 'Then' gets a value which is out of range for 'unsigned long' type

Will the ic continue to behave normally or will it malfunction?

Thank you!

Comment: let say millis() rolled over to 5 and the last count was 12345678: `(5-12345678) > 1000`; no problem.

Comment: In the unsigned arithmetics it results into distance between those two numbers, so it'll be fine. (negative numbers are stored in two's complement)

Comment: Well I don't care about rollovers or overflows until my system starts malfunctioning.